# Add INNER JOIN to my MySQL query so i can use DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, grafana, zabbix

I am working with 4 tables - Items, Hosts, History, Mappings

Items

```
hostid,itemid,name,valuemapid
10761,304827,Phone 33 44 55 66 77 88:Model of the Phone,68
10761,304827,Phone 33 44 55 66 77 88:Model of the Phone,68
10761,304827,Phone 33 44 55 66 77 88:Model of the Phone,68
10761,304828,Phone 33 44 55 66 88 88:Model of the Phone,68
10761,304828,Phone 33 44 55 66 88 88:Model of the Phone,68
10761,304828,Phone 33 44 55 66 88 88:Model of the Phone,68
10761,304829,Phone 33 44 55 77 77 88:Model of the Phone,68
10761,304829,Phone 33 44 55 77 77 88:Model of the Phone,68
10761,304820,Phone 33 44 44 66 77 88:Model of the Phone,72
10761,304820,Phone 33 44 44 66 77 88:Model of the Phone,72
```

Hosts

```
hostid,name
10761,CUCM2
```

history

```
itemid,value
304827,109
304828,109
304829,109
304829.110
```

mappings

```
valuemapid,value,newvalue
68,109,Cisco 7841
72,110,Cisco 7940
```

I wrote a query to give me the model of the phone and the count for that model, but it is counting the duplicates.  I was told that i need to add an INNER JOIN but i do not know how to do that.  Can someone help me to change my query to have an INNER JOIN for the "Items" table so it will remove all duplicate ItemID.

```
SELECT map.newvalue as 'Model of Phone', Count(*) as 'Number of Phones'
FROM items i, hosts h, history huint, mappings map
WHERE h.hostid=i.hostid AND h.name='$Hosts' AND i.itemid=huint.itemid AND i.valuemapid=map.valuemapid AND huint.value=map.value AND i.name LIKE '%Model of the Phone'
GROUP BY map.newvalue
LIMIT 100;
```

Returns

```
Model of Phone, Number of Phones
Cisco 7841, 8
Cisco 7940, 2
```

Thank you!

** UPDATE ** Using LEFT JOIN but can not figure out how to use DISTINCT

```
SELECT map.newvalue as 'Model of Phone', Count(*) as 'Number of Phones'
FROM hosts h
    LEFT JOIN items i
        ON h.hostid=i.hostid
    LEFT JOIN history_uint huint
        ON i.itemid=huint.itemid
    LEFT JOIN mappings map
        ON i.valuemapid=map.valuemapid
WHERE h.name='$Hosts' AND huint.value=map.value AND i.name LIKE '%Model of the Phone'
GROUP BY map.newvalue
ORDER BY 'Item Name' DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Why not read about JOINs, and then get back to us

Comment: Hey Strawberry... I have been reading up on JOINS all weekend since you suggested it, and have been trying to figure out how to use them, but I am still stuck. I tried w3school, sqlcourse, and just reading other answers on here, but i can not seem to transition my query to one that uses a JOIN.

Comment: There's really not much point left joining tables from which you select no columns - although in this instance huint and i are both rendered as INNER JOINs

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query rewritten using post-1992 syntax...

```
SELECT m.newvalue 'Model of Phone'
     , Count(*) 'Number of Phones'
  FROM items i
  JOIN hosts h
    ON h.hostid = i.hostid 
  JOIN history y
    ON y.itemid = i.itemid
  JOIN mappings m
    ON m.valuemapid = y.valuemapid 
   AND y.value = m.value
 WHERE h.name = '$Hosts' -- this is insecure
   AND i.name LIKE '%Model of the Phone' -- and this cannot use an index 
 GROUP 
    BY m.newvalue
 ORDER
    BY m.newvalue
 LIMIT 100;
```

Now, for further help, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you very much for working with me on this.  This has been extremely helpful for me.  The only part that i need to figure out is how to incorporate DISTINCT for i.itemid ... Is there any chance you can help me with that? I tried it here but it is throwing an error
FROM hosts h LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT itemid FROM items) i ON h.hostid=i.hostid

Comment: I don't think that's what you need. Hence why I suggest you adopt an alternative strategy towards resolving your problem, outlined in detail at the link above.

Comment: OK i have a shared session up on DB Fiddle with everything punched in if you get a chance to check it out https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b2o3Wy31hLmwSZLAfpuaVr/0#&togetherjs=IrGzVdtmMh